# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error (Node/Express noob, other solutions didn't seem to work or didn't understand them))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I looked at other answers for people who had similar issues, but I'm still a bit green in all this, so maybe I didn't understand or implement the solutions to similar issues correctly.

This is a Node/Express app that I'm trying to practice on, where I use an API to get the longitude and latitude from a search field, then use that API response data to use another API that uses longitude and latitude to get weather data. I have another app where I statically coded the latitude and longitude, and everything works fine. But, I do have nested API calls, and the post request that is new.

I am getting this error though, "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when I try and render the view. When I tested and removed the second nested API call, it worked, or if I took the second res.render out, it seemed to work.

I don't know if just what I'm doing is impossible, or if, like I said, similar issues people have had, I'm just not implementing any solutions correctly.

Ideally, I need to get the data from the nested API call, the "weatherDataResponse", data to the res.render view.
I do have it working by itself, but when I introduced the /post and top level API call, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
function latLongInfo(results) {
  let obj = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://forward-reverse-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com/v1/forward',
    params: {
      street: '',
      city: results.city,
      state: results.state,
      postalcode: results.zip,
      country: 'USA',
      'accept-language': 'en',
      polygon_threshold: '0.0'
    },
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': rapidApiKey,
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'forward-reverse-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  }
  return obj
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'idk' });
});

app.post('/getweather', (req, res, next) => {
    const cityWeatherSearch = req.body.cityWeatherSearch
    next();
    axios.request(latLongInfo(parseLatLongSearch(cityWeatherSearch)))
    .then(function (response) {
      const getLatLongInfoResponse = response.data[0]
      console.log(getLatLongInfoResponse)
      if (Object.keys(getLatLongInfoResponse).length < 1) {
      
        res.render('invalidweather', { title: 'Invalid Results' });
      }
      else {
        let lat = getLatLongInfoResponse.lat, lon = getLatLongInfoResponse.lon;
        let latLonString = `${lat},${lon}`;
        const getWeatherInfo = axios.get(`https://api.pirateweather.net/forecast/${pirateWeatherKey}/${latLonString}`)
        axios.all([getWeatherInfo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
          const weatherDataResponse = responses[0].data;
          console.log(weatherDataResponse)
          res.render('weather', { title: 'Weather Results' });
        })).catch(errors => {
          console.error(errors);
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })  
    res.end()

    
  })
```

Comment: Why are you calling next() if you're then responding to the request? Sounds like could be the issue.

Comment: @AlexisTyler, oh, that didn't make any difference. I removed and tried placing next() in places, I thought they should go from reading responses on other questions.

Comment: next() only needs to be called if that request handler isn't handling the request and you want to goto the next handler. For a standard request you shouldn't need to call it.

Comment: @AlexisTyler thank you for that information, I wasn't 100% on what it did, so I was definitely using it wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. It looks like the `next()` call is causing the issues here. I also refactored the async stuff a little so it's more readable.

```js
function latLongInfo(results) {
  let obj = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://forward-reverse-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com/v1/forward',
    params: {
      street: '',
      city: results.city,
      state: results.state,
      postalcode: results.zip,
      country: 'USA',
      'accept-language': 'en',
      polygon_threshold: '0.0'
    },
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': rapidApiKey,
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'forward-reverse-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  }
  return obj
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'idk' });
});

app.post('/getweather', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const cityWeatherSearch = req.body.cityWeatherSearch;
        const response = await axios.request(latLongInfo(parseLatLongSearch(cityWeatherSearch)));
        const getLatLongInfoResponse = response.data[0]
        console.log(getLatLongInfoResponse)

        if (Object.keys(getLatLongInfoResponse).length < 1) {
            res.render('invalidweather', { title: 'Invalid Results' });
            return;
        }

        const lat = getLatLongInfoResponse.lat;
        const lon = getLatLongInfoResponse.lon;
        const latLonString = `${lat},${lon}`;
        const getWeatherInfo = await axios.get(`https://api.pirateweather.net/forecast/${pirateWeatherKey}/${latLonString}`);
        const weatherDataResponse = getWeatherInfo.data;
        console.log(weatherDataResponse)
        res.render('weather', { title: 'Weather Results' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like that worked. I could have sworn I tried it without the next() as well. Though, I didn't try asyncing the app.post, I wasn't sure if that was acceptable with app.post.

Thank you!